# JMockit mock not getting destroyed

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, jmockit

Using JUnit for testing classes-

Have a class `TestAccess.java` having

```
static private TestAccess instance = new TestAccess();
public static TestAccess getTestAccess() {
    returns instance;
}
```

For testing a test class `A.java` used JMockit to mock the `getTestAccess` method

```
@Mock
TestAccess mockTestaccess;    

@Test
public void testMethod() {
    new MockUp<TestAccess>() {
        @mockit.Mock
        public TestAccess getTestAccess() {
            return mockTestaccess;
        }
    };

    TestAccess test=TestAccess.getTestAccess();
}
```

In another class `B.java` I don't want to use mock and call
`TestAccess.java` as follows

```
@Test
public void doTest()
{ 
    TestAccess test=TestAccess.getTestAccess();
}
```

`B.java` if run independently, the real `TestAccess` instance is returned and works fine.

However during maven run it fails as even in `B.java` the
`TestAccess.getTestAccess()` return the mock defined in `A.java` and not the real instance as expected.

Could anyone guide how can this be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

afair your example will not even run, as the `@Mock` annotation on the mockTestaccess field is not valid. I guess it should be `@Mocked`? And if so, there is no need to additionally use the `new MockUp()`, as `@Mocked` on `mockTestaccess` will already mock away all instances of `TestAccess` during the tests of that test class and afterwards will be reverted automatically. If you problem is, that `getTestAccess()` returns some subclass of `TestAccess` which then is not a mocked instance you might want to have a look at `@Capturing` which also mocks instances of subclasses.

Comment: I am using Junit for unit testing. Use @mock(org.mockito.Mock) to mock the instance. Since i wanted to mock a static method so used jMockito(mockit.MockUp). Have just edited the above statement to include mockit.MockUp which i had missed. Also the test cases do run.

Comment: You are mixing two different mocking frameworks? Why that? I'd recommend to not mixing mocking frameworks but to only use JMockit.